# Remove rows in delimited file using another file to reference Talend

Tags: file, talend

I have a file with 2 columns : `COMPANY_ID` and `ACTIVITY_ID`. This file is `n:n` relation to represent activities of the company, for example :

```
1 | 1

1 | 2

2 | 2

2 | 3

2 | 4...
```

And I have an other file with same columns but just 1:1 relation to represent the principal activity of the company, like :

```
1 | 1

2 | 3

3 | 1...
```

My question is : With Talend, how to delete in the first file the primary activity row for each company using the second file, to only keep others activities ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing an INNER JOIN between your two files, on the `COMPANY_ID` AND `ACTIVITY_ID` columns, and only getting the rows that don't match by setting "Catch lookup inner join reject" on the `tMap` output:

[image]

Output:

```
|=---------+----------=|
|COMPANY_ID|ACTIVITY_ID|
|=---------+----------=|
|1         |2          |
|2         |2          |
|2         |4          |
'----------+-----------'
```

And then write this output to a new file.